# Adding file ext icons to table column---col only shows extensions as strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, datatable

I have a DataTable that's populated by JSON data. There are three columns, the one on the left is for file extension icons and the middle column is for the document names (third column is for checkboxes).

I've been able to make it so that the first column is filled with *only* Word doc icons, but unfortunately it's not what I'm going for. I've also gotten the document extension strings to show up instead (rather than all saying "docx", they correctly say whatever the extension is).

Any thoughts on this one?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80zu32vL/) that contains a table and dummy data. It's not 100% accurate to my code because it lacks the JSON data, but it's similar.

#### JS Snippet:

```
loadTableData() {

    // -- Generating extension names -- //
    function docType(fileName) {

    let docImg = "<img src='https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/ms-word.png' />";

    let pdfImg = "<img src='https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/pdf-2.png' />";

    let xlsImg = "<img src='https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/ms-excel.png' />";

    let pptImg = "<img src='https://img.icons8.com/ios/2x/ms-powerpoint.png' />";

      let docStr = fileName.split(".")
        if (docStr.length === "docx")
        return docxImg;
      let ext = docStr.pop();
      let index = ["doc", "docx", "pdf", "xls", "nrl", "xlsx", "ppt", "pptx", "msg", "DOCX"].find(x => x == ext); // keep this line right after `let ext`
      return index ? index : docxImg;
    }
```

#### Loading table data:

```
$.noConflict();
    let tableRes = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return {
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name,
        "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
          return val.Label;
        }).join(";"),
        "Blank": "",
        "docImg": docType(obj.File.Name) // "Getting the docType of obj.File.Name"
      }
    })
```

#### Rendering table:

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        // { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Categories" }, // hidden
        { data: "docImg" },
        { data: "Titles" } // must be in last position to respond w/ checkboxes
      ],
...etc
```

---

#### Update:

```
function docType(fileName) {
      let docxImg = "<img src='https://[redacted].docx.gif' />"
      let msgImg = "<img src='https://[redacted].msg.gif' />"
      let nrlImg = "<img src='https://[redacted].nrl.gif' />"
      let pdfImg = "<img src='https://[redacted].pdf.gif' />"
      let pptxImg = "<img src='https://[redacted].pptx.gif' />"
      let xlsImg ="<img src='https://[redacted].xls.gif' />"

      let docStr = fileName.split(".")
        for (var i = 0; i < docStr.length; i++) {        
          if (docStr[i].includes('docx'))  {   return docStr[i] = docxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('doc'))   {   return docStr[i] = docxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('DOCX'))  {   return docStr[i] = docxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('rtf'))   {   return docStr[i] = docxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('msg'))   {   return docStr[i] = msgImg;   }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('nrl'))   {   return docStr[i] = nrlImg;   }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('pdf'))   {   return docStr[i] = pdfImg;   }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('pptx'))  {   return docStr[i] = pptxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('ppt'))   {   return docStr[i] = pptxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('PPT'))   {   return docStr[i] = pptxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('potx'))  {   return docStr[i] = pptxImg;  }
      else if (docStr[i].includes('xls'))   {   return docStr[i] = xlsImg;   }
        }


    } // docType()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a sample JSON source and you can change it to your need. Using datasrc in AJAX request would easily solve your problem. If you think the below has too many if's, using switch case and array would solve that too.

```
 "ajax": {
         "url": "jsonSourceHere",
         "dataSrc": function (json) {
                   for (var i = 0, ien = json.data.length; i < ien; i++) {

                        if(json.data[i][2].includes('docx')){
                             json.data[i][0]=docImg;
                            } 
                        else if(json.data[i][2].includes('pdf')){
                             json.data[i][0]=pdfImg;
                            }
                        else if(json.data[i][2].includes('xls')){
                             json.data[i][0]=pdfImg;
                            }
                        else if(json.data[i][2].includes('ppt')){
                             json.data[i][0]=pptImg;
                            }

                        }
                        return json.data;
                    },
                },
```

Comment: Hey @shubham, thanks for the answer. I got the icons to render but the document titles are duplicated right next to the icon (something like "Template1[doc icon]"). I'll update my text body with my code. It's definitely a start, though.

Comment: Update: Never mind, I changed `docStr[i] = docxImg` to `return docStr...etc` and just the icons showed up. Thank you!